# How to traverse through linked list multiple times and eliminate nodes?

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

I am trying to solve the Josephus problem using a linked list - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem. Basically we have a specified number of people - let's say 6 with k being 3. I start counting from the start of the line/ circle of people and when k is reached, that person is eliminated. I then move onto the next person and k is reset and increased until the next person is reached. We do this until one person is remaining. Note - when counting people, we skip people that have already been eliminated. So in my example of 6 people and k = 3, the first person to be eliminated would be person 3 (or in array terms, index 2), with the last person to survive being person 1 (or index = 0).

I have already solved this problem using an array and for loops. However, now I want to try to solve using a linked list as that is what I am learning. I have already created my linked list. I think the logic here is the same, count through the nodes of the linked list and eliminate the node when k is reached and so on. My problem is that I don't know how to traverse through the linked list multiple times and how to successfully eliminate until there is one (node)remaining.

Firstly, creating the linkedlist with the specified number of people (valn):

```
int counter = 0;
ListNode * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
head -> value = counter;
ListNode *current = &head;
while ( valn - 1 > counter)
{
  current -> next = malloc(sizeof*(current -> next));
  current = current -> next;
  current -> value = counter;
  current -> next = NULL;
  counter++;
}
```

Head is then returned to main (which is already provided so I am certain it is correct)

I then have a function that is supposed to count through the linked list and figure out which one to eliminate.

This is what I have so far (with valk being the number to eliminate), head and valkn are passed into this function (which is void):

```
int counter = 0;
ListNode * p = head;
while ( p != NULL)
{
  if (counter == valk)
  {
    ListNode * todelete = p;
    printListNode (todelete); // Print function that was already provided (already correct) - basically print the value of the node to be eliminated.
    deleteNode(head,todelete); // passed on to another function to delete - not sure how to delete yet
    counter = 0;
   }
  p = p -> next;
  counter++;
}
```

The header file (all the relevant libraries are included. Header file was also given):

```
typedef struct node {
  int value;
  struct node * next;
} ListNode;

void printListNode(ListNode * head);
ListNode * createList(int valn);
void eliminate(ListNode * head, int valk);
ListNode * deleteNode(ListNode * head, ListNode * todelete);
```

Expected results are as described above, if my inputs are 6 and 3, I go through the linked list until the 1st (with value 0) node is remaining.

Comment: `head->next` is not initialized.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you, but that doesnt fix everything right?

Comment: provide complete compilable code.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/josephus-circle-using-circular-linked-list/